# Annoying RStudio Behavior in debugging

Tags: r, rstudio

When I am in debug mode in a function and uses "CTRL + Enter" on an object/variable, R takes me back on line 1 of the function and prints the object variable to the console. Is this a bug or an expected behavior?

Another bug in debug mode:
- If there is a print(variable1) somewhere in the function, R will not only print to the console variable1 but also the remaining function code that comes after "print(variable1)"

Are there any ways of avoiding those behaviors of R Studio?

Thanks,

Comment: I could not reproduce either of these problems. What versions of R and RStudio are you using? Can you post the code of the function in which you're observing the misbehavior?

Comment: The version of Rstudio is the most recent as well as R. The problem appears with options(error=recover) specifically. Once you are in the debug mode there, you will notice the problem I mentioned earlier

Comment: This has bugged me for years, I would love a solution - I asked on the rstudio forum about it a long time ago and got no useful response. It really interferes with my workflow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be worth reporting to rstudio directly as it may be a bug that was left over from a change of behavior in debug mode. I looked through the `browser` help file and didn't come across this behavior.

An rstudio article from April 2016 on debugging [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627#debugging-commands), states that

> Simply pressing Enter at the console will execute the current statement and move on to the next one. This is a convenient way to step through statements quickly.

Note that most of the commands listed in this section directly match with the behavior of `browser`.

However, I've been reading Hadley's *Advanced R* recently and came across the following in section [3.2.2](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html#debugging-tools):

> There are two other slightly less useful commands that aren’t available in the toolbar:
>    * **Enter**: repeats the previous command. I find this too easy to activate accidentally, so I turn it off using options(browserNLdisabled = TRUE).
>   ...

Since *Advanced R* was published in 2014, my thinking is that this is legacy behavior that you should report to the makers of rstudio, complete with a reproducible example.